# Template type erasure

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-erasure

I am wondering whether there is a practical way of writing something like the following code using the C++17 standard:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

template <class Arg>
struct Foo
{
    using arg_type = Arg;
    using fun_type = std::function< void(Arg&) >;
    fun_type fun;
    
    void call( Arg& arg ) { fun(arg); }
};

struct Bar
{
    using map_type = std::unordered_map<std::string,Foo>; // that's incorrect
    map_type map;
    
    auto& operator[] ( std::string name ) { return map[name]; }
};
```

In the code above, the template argument of class `Foo` corresponds to the input type of some unary function which returns nothing. Different instances of `Foo` with different template types correspond to functions taking arguments of different types. The class `Bar` simply aims at assigning a name to these functions, but obviously the current declaration of the map is incorrect because it needs to know about the template type of `Foo`.

Or does it?

Comment: How do you want to call functions from the map? What should happen if you pass an arg of a wrong type?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I would expect a compile-time error due to the wrong type being used as input. My hunch is that all these instances of Foo should have essentially the same memory layout, and the compiler should still know what the argument type is because it is defined inside the class as `arg_type`.  But of course, that might just be wishful thinking (or plain wrong, I don't actually know if these classes would have the same layout).

Comment: What's stopping you from making `fun_type` a `std::any`, and make just `Foo::call<Arg>` the template?

Comment: @JonathanH But which function to call will depend on `Arg`, how is the compiler supposed to know what function to call at a given key?

Comment: @Frank That's why I asked; I don't understand the inner-workings of a compiler. I get that the type is not actually stored in memory, but the compiler normally remembers these typedefs fine without them being stored anywhere.

Comment: @JonathanH you are running into an issue of what is knowable at compile time vs what is known only at run time.  You cannot in general know which element of the collection you will be accessing (imagine it prompts the user for a key!), so it can't know the type at compile time.  You have to look at run-time techniques, like `std::visitor`.

Comment: @JDługosz `std::visitor` seems to go way beyond what I am normally comfortable with in C++. I would be very interested to see (and learn from) a solution using that, if you feel like writing one!

Comment: @Johathan_H basically _functions taking arguments of different types_ should be overloaded `operator()` in a class.  When you want to call the function for one of the map's elements, the `visitor` chooses the right one to call based on the actual type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this with a compile-time check is, unfortunately, not feasible. You can, however, provide that functionality with a runtime check.

A map's value type can only be one single type, and `Foo<T>` is a different type for each `T`. However, we can work around this by giving every `Foo<T>` a common base class, have a map of pointers to it, and use a virtual function to dispatch `call()` to the appropriate subclass.

For this though, the type of the argument must also always be the same. As mentioned by @MSalters, `std::any` can help with that.

Finally, we can wrap all that using the pimpl pattern so that it looks like there's just a single neat `Foo` type:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <any>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
public:
  template<typename T, typename FunT>
  void set(FunT fun) {
      pimpl_ = std::make_unique<FooImpl<T, FunT>>(std::move(fun));
  }

  // Using operator()() instead of call() makes this a functor, which
  // is a little more flexible.
  void operator()(const std::any& arg) {
      assert(pimpl_);
      pimpl_->call(arg);
  }
  
private:
    struct IFooImpl {
      virtual ~IFooImpl() = default;
      virtual void call( const std::any& arg ) const = 0; 
    };

    template <class Arg, typename FunT>
    struct FooImpl : IFooImpl
    {
        FooImpl(FunT fun) : fun_(std::move(fun)) {}
        
        void call( const std::any& arg ) const override {
            fun_(std::any_cast<Arg>(arg));
        }

    private:
        FunT fun_;
    };

  std::unique_ptr<IFooImpl> pimpl_;
};


// Usage sample
#include <iostream>

void bar(int v) {
    std::cout << "bar called with: " << v << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo> table;

    table["aaa"].set<int>(bar);

    // Even works with templates/generic lambdas!
    table["bbb"].set<float>([](auto x) {
        std::cout << "bbb called with " << x << "\n";
    });

    table["aaa"](14);
    table["bbb"](12.0f);
}
```

[see on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vffsrr9Ke)

Comment: Amazing! This seems to fail at runtime with `bad any_cast` if we call the function with the wrong input type, which is great. I'll experiment a bit more with the code but I think that's my answer!

Comment: I'm curious about why you define the destructor of `IFooImpl` with `= default`: is this just good practice, or is it actually important here? Do I understand correctly that using `unique_ptr` for the pimpl pattern also prevents instances of `Foo` being copied?

Comment: @JonathanH It's because since we will be deleting pointers of type `IFooImpl`, the destructor MUST be `virtual`. I "could" have written `virtual ~IFooImpl() {}`, but using `default` makes my intent clearer.

Comment: @JonathanH With regards to copying: correct. There are movable though. If you want them copyable, you can simply use `std::shared_ptr`, or add a `clone()` virtual method to `IFooImpl` and write a copy/assign constructor/operator for `Foo`.